# I want to add a \ to the end of an input

Tags: excel, vba, input

```
Path = InputBox("Paste the path of the folder:" & vbCrLf & "Pls end your path with a  '\'" & vbCrLf & "e.g D:\work\path\")
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
```

I want to add a \ to the end of my input, my code dont work if the user forgets to put in the slash. How do I do this?

I tried

```
Filename = Dir(Path & "\" & "*.xlsx")
```

Comment: `If Right(Path,1) <> "\" then Path = Path & "\"`

Comment: Why not just use a folder picker instead of an `InputBox`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub slashAtEnd()
    Dim Filename, Path
    For Each Path In Array("C:\temp", "C:\temp\")
        Filename = Dir(Path & Mid("\", 1 - (Path Like "*\")) & "*.xlsx")   ' works
        Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")   'works too, even if with two \ at the end of "C:\temp\\"
        Debug.Print Filename
    Next
End Sub
'Output:
'Test.xlsx
'Test.xlsx
```